# add $id = $_GET['student_id']; and show all same id

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to show all row with the same id using $_GET['student_id'] but datatables error this is my code. Once I get the id from url for example : 
example.com/example.php?=2222

all of the id with 2222 will show up.

Fetch.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
include('function.php');
$query = '';
$output = array();
$id = $_GET['student_id'];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM personal WHERE student_id LIKE "%'.$_GET["student_id"].'%" ';
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = array();
$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $image = '';
    if($row["image"] != '')
    {
        $image = '<img src="upload/'.$row["image"].'" class="img-thumbnail" width="50" height="35" />';
    }
    else
    {
        $image = '';
    }
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $row["student_id"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["firstname"]." ".$row['middlename']." ".$row['lastname'];
    $sub_array[] = '<a href="edit.php?student_id='.$row["student_id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs update">Personal Info</a>'." ".
    '<button type="button" id="'.$row["student_id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs update">Grades</button>'." ".
    '<button type="button" id="'.$row["student_id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs update">Payment</button>';
    $sub_array[] = '<a href="view.php?student_id='.$row["student_id"].'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs update">View</a>';
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row["student_id"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Delete</button>';
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}
$output = array(
    "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_total_all_records(),
    "data"              =>  $data
);
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

DATATABLES Call
 I want to show all row with the same id using $_GET['student_id'] but datatables error this is my code. Once I get the id from url for example : 
example.com/example.php?=2222

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add_button').click(function(){
            $('#user_form')[0].reset();
        });

        var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
            "processing":true,
            "serverSide":true,
            "order":[],
            "ajax":{
                url:"fetch.php",
                type:"POST"
            },
            "columnDefs":[
                {
                    "targets":[0, 3, 4],
                    "orderable":false,
                },
            ],

        });


        $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
            var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"delete.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{user_id:user_id},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return false;   
            }
        });


    });
    </script>
```

This is all of my code relating in my past question. 
 I want to show all row with the same id using $_GET['student_id'] but datatables error this is my code. Once I get the id from url for example : 
example.com/example.php?=2222

Comment: you don't have `student_id` in your URL. Is it typo? Should be `example.com/example.php?student_id=2222`

Comment: sorry its a typo. but lets assume its that url is right. but datatables always show an error

Comment: why not `SELECT * FROM personal WHERE student_id=$id` you shouldn't be using like, and you need to learn about sql injection

Comment: You know the `->fetchAll()` returns numeric and associative values, right?

Answer (score 0):

First thing it seems like you're using `PDO` as your data base access layer and you're `prepare`ing your `SQL` but you're making a big mistake using the variable directly inside the `SQL` it self. Don't do that it opens the doors to `SQL Injection` if you already know how to prepare the `SQL` then use bind to bind the variables to variable names.

Also I see you're binding `$_GET['student_id']` to `$id` but not using it any way your really don't need to bind received variables to new variables.

To answer your problem try this,

Your Code:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM personal WHERE student_id LIKE "%'.$_GET["student_id"].'%" ';
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

My Suggestion:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM personal WHERE student_id LIKE :id ';
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement -> bindParam(':id', $_GET['student_id']);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```